# How to read messages on iphone with xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios

How to read messages on iphone with xamarin?

If not permission access. can I jailbreak iphone to read message ?

Please,give me a solution

Thanks u

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Apple doesn't expose any public API that allows you to access a users messages.